# No value for JSONObject Android

Tags: android, json

I have been trying to solve `No value for JSONObject` error without any success. I am getting the JSON response and using a `try` block to create the JSONObject. I am testing for incorrect log in credentials which means the JSON reponse is like

`{"success":false,"messages":"Incorrect email\/password combination"}`

How can I get past this. Here's my code.

```
  try {


        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("success");

       // Check for error node in json
        if (!error) {
             // user successfully logged in
             // Create login session
             mSessionManager.setLogin(true);

             // Now store the user in SQLite
             JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
             String firstName = user.getString("firstname");
             String lastName = user.getString("lastname");
             String email = user.getString("email");
             String created_at = user
                                .getString("created_at");
             String uid = String.valueOf(user.getInt("user_id"));

             // Inserting row in users table
             mSQLiteHandler.addUser(firstName, lastName, email, uid, created_at);

             // Launch main activity
             Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                Pedometer.class);
             startActivity(intent);
             finish();

          } else {
              // Error in login. Get the error message
              String errorMsg = jObj.getString("messages");
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
          // JSON error
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
           "Json error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I have tried putting the block of code inside the if block inside `if(jObj.has("user")` but no error is being shown. The progress dialog shows and hides immediately

Comment: at what point in the code u experience issue please point it ??

Comment: @AalapPatel after getting the response `{"success":false,"messages":"Incorrect email\/password combination"}` which is been received right before the try block

Comment: are u using retrofit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you are trying to get values when success is fasle ... try to retrieve it when success is true

```
 try {


    change ---->    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response.body().toString);
        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("success");

       // Check for error node in json
  change   ---->   if (error) {
//retrieve values here
}
```

Comment: Thanks..yes works perfectly. Was a logical error. In the api I am using success and not error so does make sense to change error to success so that it is `if(success)` and not `if(error`)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something to Akshay's answer, For best practice you should always try to check whether response is successful or not. Like this..

```
if(response.isSuccessful()){

       String responseBody = response.body().string();
       try {


    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(responseBody); //here was the cause mentioned by Akshay
    boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("success");

   // Check for error node in json
    if (!error) {
         // user successfully logged in
         // Create login session
         mSessionManager.setLogin(true);

         // Now store the user in SQLite
         JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
         String firstName = user.getString("firstname");
         String lastName = user.getString("lastname");
         String email = user.getString("email");
         String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");
         String uid = String.valueOf(user.getInt("user_id"));

         // Inserting row in users table
         mSQLiteHandler.addUser(firstName, lastName, email, uid, created_at);

         // Launch main activity
         Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            Pedometer.class);
         startActivity(intent);
         finish();

      } else {
          // Error in login. Get the error message
          String errorMsg = jObj.getString("messages");
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
      // JSON error
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
       "Json error: " + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
    else{
          //here you should observe error caused..

    }
```